# How to use protoc.exe in Windows for eclipse luna?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, eclipse-luna

I am using Eclipse IDE, Version: Luna Release (4.4.0) to build a project. I am trying to use google protocol buffers. But I don't know how to use protoc to compile .proto files and then how to use the source code to build my project. I have downloaded compiler and source code from https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/downloads

But how to integrate it with Eclipse IDE, I have no clue. As I am a beginner in protobuf, it will be a great help to me if someone could explain it step by step that how to use the protoc compiler and source code in eclipse.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're letting Eclipse manage your builds, then try going under Project Properties, Builders, and adding a new builder that runs protoc.